# Where to put conditional rendering logic in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on a component where I need to show different icons based on a status:

**component.html**

```
<app-form-row label="Status">
    <span>
      <i *ngIf="getStatus === 'READY'" class="check circle outline icon green"></i>
      <i *ngIf="getStatus === 'UPDATING'" class="notched circle loading icon orange"></i>
      <i *ngIf="getStatus === 'FAILED'" class="times circle outline icon red"></i>
    </span>
</app-form-row>
```

**component.ts**

```
get getStatus(): string {
    return this.data.status;
  }
```

---

Another approach is to move the condition in TS.

**component.html**

```
<app-form-row label="Status">
    <span>
      <i [ngClass]=“classByStatus"></i>
    </span>
</app-form-row>
```

**component.ts**

```
get classByStatus(): string {
    return {
      'READY': 'check circle outline icon green',
      'UPDATING': 'notched circle loading icon orange',
      'FAILED': 'times circle outline icon red'
    }[this.data.status];
  }
```

**What are the pros and cons for each approaches?**
**Any other way to solve this use case?**

Comment: That should probably be `ngSwitch`, but use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TBH, both are bad approaches. Binding a function to a directive (and also in template interpolation `{{ }}`) with default change detection strategy would trigger the function for each change detection cycle. It might not be a huge issue initially, but might lead to performance issues later.

Ideal solution would be to apply the conditions directly in the `ngClass`

```html
<i
  class="circle icon"
  [ngClass]="{
    'READY': 'check outline green', 
    'UPDATING': 'notched loading orange', 
    'FAILED': 'times outline red'
  }[data.status]"
>
</i>
```